# Something works not in we thought way

Tags: sentence-construction

scenario:

A software has a foo function. This function works well. But Someone just mis-think foo function should work in another way. So can we say:

> Foo function works well. It's just not what you think how it should
>   work.

Is that sentence correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds clumsy and non-standard. That meaning could be expressed as:

> The Foo function works properly. But it doesn't work in the way you are expecting.

or

> The Foo function works well. It just doesn't work in the way you think it does.

or

> The Foo function works well. It just doesn't work as you expect it to.

or

> The Foo function works well. It works in a different way than you are expecting.

Other variants are possible.
Any of these could and probably should be followed by a more-or-less detailed description of how Foo actually works, and how the listener seems to have misunderstood it.

But "...what you think how it should work." does not go together. "What you think" is fine, and so is "how you think it should work", but not the combination.